# ERROR: Could not build wheels for pendulum, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, rpa

I'm trying to install `rpaframework` via `pip install rpaframework` on my laptop in pycharm ide.

Environment:

- Window 10
- Python 3.12.2
- pip 24.0

Error:

```
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:/Program Files/Python312/python.exe', 'build.py']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pendulum
Failed to build pendulum
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pendulum, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

[image: error screenshot]

What I tried :

- `pip install pendulum==2.0.3`
- `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`

Please help. Tried most of the solutions I could find online, and as the last resort, posting it on stackoverflow.

Comment: 1. do not post pictures, copy text here. 2.  post a **full** error. That doesn't give any hints of what actually happened.

Comment: But since the issue looks like "failed to build a wheel" and pendulum 2.0.3 ships wheel only for python 3.7. Im willing to bet that you dont have MSVC compiler installed: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers